# Switching from Nvidia 510 to 525 open kernel driver fails

Tags: drivers, nvidia

In Ubuntu 20.04 Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers I switched from the 510 driver to the `nvidia-driver-525-open`.  I entered my password (twice) and I got these error messages

[image: Error when upgrading to Nvidia open-kernel 525 driver]

The upgrade process completed and I restarted, which was very slow.  After restarting Software & Updates shows the `nvidia-driver-525-open` in use.  `nvidia-smi` shows `No devices were found`.  If I try to run a cuda binary it fails.  It ran before with the 510 driver.

Is this a bug in the 525-open driver, or the install process?

Comment: Most likely it's just the "-open" messing up some parsing of the filename for a version.  Try the nvidia-driver-525 driver.